# HTML Tables aren't aligning correctly with CSS

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have a series of tables that are stack on top of one another.  They could be a single table, but for functional reasons, they are split up.  They look something like this:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/LICwuVF.png]

Now, the problem is that they aren't lining up as I would expect them to.  The code that governs them looks like so  (It is quite lengthy):

http://pastebin.com/eWhEPzF5

The structure is 3 tables deep, and you can see it poke outside of the most inner table when it splits tables.  Global styles are pretty simple:

```css
body *
    {
    font-family:'Consolas';
    font-size:12pt;
    padding:0px;

    }
table
    {
        border: 0px;
        border-style:solid;
        padding:0px;
        border-spacing:0px;
        border-collapse:collapse; 
    }
td
    {
        padding:0px;
        border:0px;
        height:25px;
        border-style:solid;
    }
```

--

Now, I originally thought the input boxes is what was screwing up the alignment, but after removing them completely, nothing changed.  In fact, adding rows one by one, it only 'breaks' when I add the first row of the first table ("Oh my look at all this data").

I doubled checked all the styling and everything and it all is correct.

Why aren't these cells lining up?

Comment: Besides your problem, please apply your font styles and the padding to `body` and not `body *`. The asterisk there selects ALL elements inside body (basically all visible elements on your site). **Edit:** What about the `width`-attribute on your tables?

Comment: your html seems invalid. The first error I saw is on line 52, where you close a nested table that was never opened... Try validating your code http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `class`, `<col>` tag and `colspan` to set equals width in each tables.

add `table-layout:fixed;` to avoid `width` to be resized by content.

Now, if you make a codepen from your pastbin it would be confortable to re-use your code and see what you are up to , to devellop further.
regards

Comment: That is the solution!  I did not even know <col> was a thing until today.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try using this on all the tables:

```
table-layout:fixed;
```

[Table layout property in w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/pr_tab_table-layout.asp)

Regards,
Nikola

Comment: i would propose this as well :) http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/table-layout

Comment: Sure, w3.org is always better than w3schools :)

Answer (score 1):

There are various places you have the typo

```
cellWdith310
```

Assuming you've left out some CSS then that could be the issue

UPDATE:
Here's a JS fiddle. There were just various problems with your HTML such as not having enough TDs in the last table etc.  Diff the source see what's different

http://jsfiddle.net/AhLAD/7/

Comment: After ctrl+f-ing the entire document, there are a lot of places with the 'Wdith' typo.  Thanks for the catch!